# What is the relationship between covariance matrix and contour plot?

Tags: self-study, decision-theory, apriori

> [image]

From this video,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fr5wML3y1Xk

I deduced that here, $a==b$ and $c<0$.

**Here are my questions,**

(1) What does it mean by "equal loss values of errors"?

(2) What happens when a-priori probabilities of $C_1$ and $C_2$ are equal or unequal?

(3) Can you please supply me some link of study materials?

Comment: Can you describe or copy the description of the plot/image? What do the ellipses we are seeing represent? Also, my guess for "equal loss values of errors" would be an output that gives the same error-value regardless of the actual label. So if $o$ is our output and $E$ is our error-function/cost-function: $E(o, C_1)==E(o,C_2)$

Comment: @dimpol, see the edit.

Comment: If the horizontal and vertical axes are assumed to be drawn on the same scale, then it is not the case that $a=b$, because these describe the spreads of the data along those axes and the spreads clearly differ.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that both axes are on the same scale, you have $a<b$ and $c<0$.  The contour plot for a bivariate normal distribution with the specified covariance matrix is an ellipse of the form:

$$\begin{align}
\text{const} 
&= \begin{bmatrix} x_a - \mu_a & x_b - \mu_b \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a & c \\ c & b \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix} x_a - \mu_a \\ x_b - \mu_b \end{bmatrix} \\[12pt]
&= \frac{1}{ab-c^2} \begin{bmatrix} x_a - \mu_a & x_b - \mu_b \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} b & -c \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x_a - \mu_a \\ x_b - \mu_b \end{bmatrix} \\[12pt]
&= \frac{b (x_a - \mu_a)^2 - 2c (x_a - \mu_a) (x_b - \mu_b) + a (x_b - \mu_b)^2}{ab-c^2}, \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

where $\mu_a$ and $\mu_b$ are the means of the two variables.  You can tell that $c<0$ because the ellipse slopes in the negative direction (i.e., from top-left to bottom-right).  You can tell that $a<b$ because the ellipse is narrower on the horizontal axis (for variable $x_a$) than on the vertical axis (for variable $x_b$).

The remaining questions pertaining to the probabilities for the classification problem is unclear to me, and more specification of the problem is needed.

Comment: Kindly, write something on the relationship between $P(C_1)$ and $P(C_2)$. What happens when they are equal or unequal?